# Installing the tensorflow models object-detection package installs every version of pandas

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-model-garden

While following the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md), my device attempts to install every version of pandas. The output looks like  this:

...

```
 Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tf-models-official->object-detection==0.1) (0.8)
Collecting tf-models-official
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (711 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 711 kB 3.1 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tf-models-official->object-detection==0.1) (0.8)
Collecting tf-models-official
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (711 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 711 kB 1.5 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tf-models-official->object-detection==0.1) (0.8)
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.1.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (9.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 9.5 MB 3.7 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2018.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from apache-beam->object-detection==0.1) (2018.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tf-models-official->object-detection==0.1) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tf-models-official->object-detection==0.1) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tf-models-official->object-detection==0.1) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tf-models-official->object-detection==0.1) (0.8)
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.1.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (9.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 9.5 MB 1.3 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2018.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from apache-beam->object-detection==0.1) (2018.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tf-models-official->object-detection==0.1) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tf-models-official->object-detection==0.1) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages 
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.1.2.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.2 MB 3.4 MB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2018.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from apache-beam->object-detection==0.1) (2018.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tf-models-official->object-detection==0.1) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tf-models-official->object-detection==0.1) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages 
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.1.1.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.2 MB 6.8 MB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2018.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from apache-beam->object-detection==0.1) (2018.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tf-models-official->object-detection==0.1) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages 
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.1.0.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.2 MB 379 kB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done

  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2018.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from apache-beam->object-detection==0.1) (2018.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/paige/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages 
Collecting pandas

  Downloading pandas-1.0.5.tar.gz (5.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.0 MB 90 kB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
```

... etc.

This feels wrong, and takes a long,long time to run. Is this the intended behavior? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of Python, Tensorflow, and Pip and try again, If this doesn't work you can mention the latest version of the Pandas in the setpu.py file here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py.